# My iPhone says I need to do billing

Tags: iphone

My iPhone is saying I need to do billing but there is not a none button by the credit cards what do I do I need to download a app for my cheerleading

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you have an unpaid balance from a previous transaction. This can happen for a number of reasons such as insufficient funds in your bank account.

If you have an unpaid transaction, iTunes requires you to add a valid payment method before you can continue using the iTunes Store/App Store. Even for free items.

You can see if you have any unpaid purchases by going into your ['Purchase History'](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204088) (see example below) or contacting iTunes Support via email or phone.

[image]

More info: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203005